# How to get version of installed Juju

Tags: juju

I want to see what version of Juju is installed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`juju --version` will return the installed client version. You can also use the `juju version` syntax.

All of the commands can be listed by running `juju help commands`

Comment: Wow, how could I have missed this :o